# Swift TableView doesn't return numbersOfRow

Tags: swift, tableview, swifty-json

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{        
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!    
    var mass = [String]()
    var jDatas = datas()    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/AAPL.json")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
            } else {
                if let content = data {
                    let myJson = JSON(data: content)                    
                    for item in myJson["dataset"]["data"] {                        
                        let dates = "open \(String(describing: item.1[1].string)))"                 
                        self.mass.append(dates)                      
                    }       
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mass.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SimpleTableViewCell
        cell.datasLabel?.text = "some text"
        return cell
    }
}
```

So my problem is that numberOfRowInSection doesn't work, I tried everything, can someone say whats the problem?

When I'm trying to debug the code it says that theres 0 in my massive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to reload the `tableView` after your for loop in `dataTask`'s closure, so simply reload the `tableView` also on main thread.

```
for item in myJson["dataset"]["data"] {                        
   let dates = "open \(String(describing: item.1[1].string)))"                 
   self.mass.append(dates)                      
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: tnx, its working) but now when I'm trying to take my massive in tableView it says *open nil)*

Comment: @SerjSemenov Welcome mate, Thats because array doesn't contains string value but it is number try like this way `let dates = "open \(String(item.1[1].doubleValue)))"`

Comment: OMG I didn't noticed that, tnx a lot )